# Define and apply Gradle task multiple times with the same name

Tags: java, docker, gradle

So this library https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker defines the task `docker`.

I have a Java multi-project build and I would like to build 3 docker images for the 3 sub-applications that are insde.

I can't define in `build.gradle`:

```
docker {
    name 'my-registry.jfrog.io/projecta:' + System.getenv("RELEASE_VERSION")
    dockerfile project.file("docker/projecta/Dockerfile")
    files 'a/build/libs/a.jar'
}

docker {
    name 'my-registry.jfrog.io/projectb:' + System.getenv("RELEASE_VERSION")
    dockerfile project.file("docker/projectb/Dockerfile")
    files 'b/build/libs/b.jar'
}
```

because only the last will execute. Only the b image is listed upon my `docker images` command.

How can I build 3 images with this Gradle library?

Comment: do you use multiproject build, with `a` and `b` configured as sub-projects?  then I think you could apply `docker` plugin separatly in both subproject, and configure the `docker` extension in both suproject's build files.

Comment: Of course, Thank you!